# Do cold battery capacity de-ratings apply at low currents?

Tags: batteries

I've read that NiMH and Lithium chemistries will only supply around half of their rated capacity when used at low temperatures (say around 0 degrees C).

Many sources also mention an increase in internal resistance and it is inferred that the two characteristics are related.

Now what if I'm working on a very low current application relative to the C rating of the battery? Say 0.01C. Do I still have to assume I will only get roughly half the mAh out of the battery? (My reasoning is that at low C discharge rates the internal resistance of the battery is less significant.)

Comment: Refer to this link we have discussed this lot http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214834/car-battery-capacity-in-colder-countries/214925?noredirect=1#comment458361_214925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning about the internal resistance is correct.  To illustrate it, I found this plot for different discharge rates at low temperatures.

[image]

Energizer L91 Lithium Battery Capacity and Temperature Curve.  [Source](http://toolguyd.com/flashlight-tool-batteries-cold-weather/).

There is another discussion about temperature and discharge rate [here](http://www.mpoweruk.com/soc.htm).